# Trying to run simple PIL python example, can't convert jpeg to float

Tags: python, image, image-processing, python-imaging-library

so I wrote a simple python script

```
from PIL import Image
from pylab import *
im = array(Image.open('sample.jpg'))
imshow(im)
```

and i get this error from IDLE

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/michael/Dropbox/OpenCV/greyscale.py", line 5, in <module>
    imshow(im)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2722, in     imshow
   imlim=imlim, resample=resample, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes.py", line 7091, in imshow
im.set_data(X)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 418, in     set_data
    raise TypeError("Image data can not convert to float")
TypeError: Image data can not convert to float
```

basically says i can not covert my image to float, anyone know what im missing

Answer (score 17):

I know this is coming very later but I thought I should answer just in case anyone else had the same problem. I ran into the same problem and the issue was the image I loaded did not exist in the project folder.so you need to check that `sample.jpg` exist and that it loads properly before using it.

```
if os.path.isfile('sample.jpg'): im = array(Image.open('sample.jpg'))
if im == None or im.size == 0: 
   print 'Image loaded is empty'
   sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: BUT IM GETTING THIS ERROR----> if os.path.isfile('5.jpg'): im = array(Image.open('5.jpg'))                                                                                             
NameError: name 'array' is not defined

Comment: if os.path.isfile('5.jpg'): im = array(Image.open('5.jpg')) TypeError: must be char, not instance

Comment: @vinta You need `from numpy import array`

Answer (score 2):

What you have is close.
Looking at the imshow docs, you need to pass either an Image OR a data array.
This should work:

```
from PIL import Image
from pylab import *
im = Image.open('sample.jpg')
imshow(im)
```

Here's what imshow() is expecting:

> "X may be a float array, a uint8 array or a PIL image."

There are some more details here:
 http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> plt.imshow(im.reshape(im.shape[0], im.shape[1]), cmap=plt.cm.Greys)
```