# PIL Image data can not convert to float

Tags: python

I am working through a few Python image tutorials.  It seems that the greatest challenge every time I try something new in Python is just getting it to work!  I have imported the PIL code and am trying to run the short snippet below in Spyder on Python 2.7.8

```
from PIL import Image
from pylab import *

im = array(Image.open('test.jpg'))

imshow(im)

show()
```

When I do so, I get "Image data can not convert to float" error.

I tried to do the same in an iPython notebook and received the same error.  When I run pip freeze it shows that I have PIP 1.1.7 installed.  Of note, I installed PIP using the executable at the host site, not with PIP.  I am also using the Spyder instance that comes with Anaconda.

Any advice?

Comment: Have you tried this solution? http://stackoverflow.com/a/16586141/742269

Comment: Yes, I saw that post.  When I take out the array portion I get the following error "The _imaging C module is not installed" (maybe that's telling me something?)  When I check to make sure that the file is in the path it confirms that the file is there.

Comment: On that solution you don't need to get rid of the `array` part: `im = array(Image.open('sample.jpg'))`

Comment: Sorry, I did both "solutions" that were shown and neither fixed the problem.  I'm confident that I am accessing the image (which is what the first one was looking for) and taking it out of the array which is mentioned in the second one) gave the new error.

Comment: I followed the recommendations at [link](http://effbot.org/zone/pil-imaging-not-installed.htm) and Import Error:  DLL load failed:  %1 is not a valid Win32 application.  I am now working on installing Pillow to see if it works better.

Comment: OK, that solved it.  I would recommend installing Pillow.

Answer (score 0):

After trying other solutions posted I discovered that PIL may be out of date with my newer Python build (see link in comments).  Once Pillow was installed the issue was resolved.